# How to fix virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: and virtualenvwrapper.sh issue...?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm currently using mac and whenever, I'm launching the terminal it will show like code below. I tried all the method in stackoverflow but it didnt work, so I'm posting my own. **Please help me to fix this.** I had tried "sudo apt-get install python3-pip" or "sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper". They are all installed

**Message**

```
Last login: Tue Aug 18 22:33:59 on ttys000
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

**Which python command**

```
/usr/bin/python
```

**Python version command**

```
Python 2.7.16
```

**Which python3 command**

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

**Python version3 command**

```
Python 3.7.4
```

**pip3 --version command**

```
pip 19.3.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: The err comes after what command? If you have all set in bash file, please share that as well

Comment: I didnt put any comment. This error will appear when i just open terminal

Answer (score 0):

Virtualenvwrapper needs to know correct python3 path.

Try to set variable containing path to python3 running following command:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

If it helps, you should run this command every time you initialize a bash or zsh session.

To do this automatically, add the command to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file, depending on what you use.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like your Virtualenv/Virtualenvwrapper install broke (it happens!). If you don't know what that is/means, the easiest thing to do is to look through dotfiles in your home directory, identify which ones are being run by your shell of choice (e.g. `.zshrc`, `.profile`, `.bashrc`, etc), and comment out (or remove, it's up to you) the line that ends with `virtualenvwrapper.sh`.

Comment: So ... the solution is don't use virtualenvwrapper?

Comment: Well when I answered I figured the question wasn't "how do I fix my virtualenvwrapper install?" but "how do I make this message I don't understand go away?" That said, it's a fair point that I didn't include links/instructions for diagnosing a broken install of virtualenvwrapper.